# 'SQLite Error 1: 'near "(": syntax error'.' with cross apply in query?

Tags: c#, sqlite

I haven't been able to find the answer anywhere.. if there's any documentation revolving around this please share them with me.

I'm trying to send back a query to pull a value that's in nested json to use for my result, but whenever I run it I get a 'SQLite Error 1: 'near (": syntax error'. I've ran the query by itself many times to verify it's not a syntax error. My suspicion is that the compiler doesn't know how to convert "cross apply" into LINQ to run against the db set. Again, I haven't been able to find any documentation regarding this so it's only a suspicion. Thoughts?

```
var orders = _context.Orders.AsQueryable();

orders = orders.FromSql($@"
SELECT OR.*
FROM Orders OR
CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(OR.json, '$.Buyers') WITH (ExpiredDate DateTime2 '$.ExpiredDate')
WHERE ExpiredDate = {DateTime.Now}");
```

Comment: Have you tried to run your query in sqlite ? not withstanding any other issue, i am not sure you can run this sort of query anyway

Comment: That query isn't close to valid sqlite syntax...